# Why does the MC34063 application note show different Vf and Vsat?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, switching-regulator

On Semiconductor application note [AN920/D](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AN920-D.PDF), on page 6 in the *Step−Down Switching Regulator Design Example*, uses a Vf=0.8V for the external diode:

$$
\frac {t_{on}} {t_{off}} = 
\frac {5.0 + 0.8}{21.6 - 0.8 - 5.0}
$$

But in Figure 9 they show the diode to be a 1N5819:

[image: Example step-down configuration]

This diode - for a forward current of 100mA - has a forward voltage of about 340mV. Why do they use 800mV? Their cited forward current for the example configuration is only 50mA, so it would be even lower than 340mV.

Similarly, the second 0.8V term in the equation above is for the saturation voltage of the output switch. Their example uses the μA78S40 but I would be using the MC34063 which they claim is inter-changeable. The [MC34063 datasheet](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/03/f9/c4/3d/7f/eb/4c/5e/CD00001232.pdf/files/CD00001232.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00001232.pdf)'s information on Vsat is difficult to interpret. I think I would be using Darlington mode if I were to translate from the example configuration as closely as possible. However, the data sheet only has data for Isw=1A (Vcesat ~ 450mV) and I would be well below that; also that figure assumes Rsc between the drive collector and Vcc to be 82 ohms but the example configuration uses only 2.7 ohms.

[image: MC34063 datasheet]

What would be a practical Vcesat to use in this case? Or am I forced to characterize on my own?

Comment: The 0.8 V might be a relic from their internal diode, but does it really matter using a worst case?  The typical Vsat of the darlington seems to be 1 V.